# Convert string to portable filename with <filesystem> or Boost.Filesystem

Tags: c++, filenames, c++20, boost-filesystem

Is there a simple way, with `<filesystem>` or `<boost/filesystem.hpp>` to convert a sequence of bytes, perhaps represented by `std::vector<char>` into a portable filename string such that the result can be converted back to the input sequence?

---

As an example, if a platform permits a filename to be comprised of characters from ranging from [a,f] and [0,9]. A conversion function that suits the above constraint might be one that simply outputs each character in it's two-digit hex equivalent, so {'a', 'b'} would become "6768" as 'a' -> 97 -> 0x67, and 'b' -> 98 -> 0x68.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking for here. The first paragraph seems pretty clear (build a `path` from the input string, then call `path::generic_u8string`), but the second paragraph is talking about a byte encoding scheme that would not be portable across different filesystems. And that answer wouldn't be appropriate for that.

Comment: @NicolBolas To clarify, consider an example where the input sequence of bytes is "/a/b", now the `std::path` instance constructed from that path will lead to a file 'b' within the directory 'a'. Now we have lost enough information to get back "/a/b" from simply the filename. If you were to apply the question constriants to the input sequence "/a/b", the resulting file (with some name) would have a name that would allow us to 1) get back the original sequence, and 2) result in a filename by it's own, and not a file within another directory.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that you don't really understand what's going on in `filesystem::path`. Like, everything you said about what `path` contained was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It took me several days to write this :/.

My personal objective here was to following:

1. Each unique input string must result in a unique filename. In other words, the conversion must be "one-to-one" which implies that it is also reversible, as was requested by the OP.
2. As many characters as possible must be kept the same; at least, the filename should be mostly human readable and look much like the original string.
3. When nothing else goes, characters should be escaped as is usual for url-encoding: a percentage followed by the byte value in hexadecimal.
4. The escape character (%) itself is escaped with two of them (%%), unless another translation is requested.

I wanted simple things, like the ability to have spaces replaced by underscores; and since underscores might also occur frequently, I don't want those escaped with `%2F`, but with something neat, like a (multi-byte) unicode character.

I decided to only support UTF8 strings therefore, and be able to treat any utf8 glyph as a translatable 'character'; that is: you can translate single glyphs into different glyphs (including all 1-byte ASCII values).

It is not possible to translate multi-glyph sequences with my implementation, but since it is based on a `Dictionary` class, most of the code should be reusable if anyone wants to add support for that.

Making sure that every string, under any possible translation is reversible turned out to be non-trivial to say the least.

```c
  //   From
  //    |
  //    v
  //  .----------------------------------------.
  //  |                                        |
  //  |                                    j--------.
  //  |                                        |    |
  //  |                              i     k   |    |
  //  |                     .--------|-----|---+----|----------------.
  //  |                     |1   a   v     | b--->B v               2|<-- To
  //  |                  .--->M  |   I     |   |    J                |
  //  |                  |  |  E v         |   |                     |
  //  |                  |  |  ^ A   d  c  |   |                     |
  //  |          .-------|--+--|-----|--|--|---+---------.           |
  //  |          |       m  |3 | g   |  v  v   |         |           |
  //  |          |          |  e |   |  C  K   |         |           |
  //  |          | p        |    v   |         |         |           |
  //  |    l     | |   n  o-->O  G h |       f------------->F        |
  //  '----|-----+-|---|----+------|-|---------'         |           |
  //       |     | |   |    |4     v v                   |           |
  //       |     | |   |    |      H D                   |           |
  //       |     | |   `----------------------------------->N        |
  //       |     | `--------->P                          |           |
  //       `----------------->L                          |           |
  //             |          |                            |           |
  //             |          '----------------------------+-----------'
  //             |                                       |
  //             |              q                        |   r
  //             |                                       |
  //             |                                       |<-- Illegal
  //             '---------------------------------------'
```

(and that doesn't even include escape characters)

But I think I succeeded. If anyone manages to find arguments to `u8string_to_filename` that does not convert back with `filename_to_u8string` let me know!

First of all I needed a function that returns the number of bytes of a glyph:

```c
// Returns the length of the UTF8 encoded glyph, which is highly
// recommended to be either guaranteed correct UTF8, or points
// inside a zero terminated string.
//
// If the pointer does not point to a legal UTF8 glyph then 1 is returned.
// The zero termination is necessary to detect the end of the string
// in the case that the apparent encoded glyph length goes beyond the string.
//
int utf8_glyph_length(char8_t const* glyph)
{
  // The length of a glyph is determined by the first byte.
  // This magic formula returns 1 for 110xxxxx, 2 for 1110xxxx,
  // 3 for 11110xxx and 0 otherwise.
  int extra = (0x3a55000000000000 >> ((*glyph >> 2) & 0x3e)) & 0x3;
  // Detect if there are indeed `extra` bytes that follow the first
  // one, each of which must begin with 10xxxxxx to be legal UTF8.
  int i = 0;
  while (++i <= extra)
    if (glyph[i] >> 6 != 2)
      return 1;         // Not legal UTF8 encoding.
  return 1 + extra;
}
```

You can find this file [here](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/utf8_glyph_length.cxx).

Next we need a simple `Dictionary` class:

```c
class Dictionary
{
 private:
  std::vector<std::u8string_view> m_words;

 public:
  Dictionary(std::u8string const&);

  size_t size() const { return m_words.size(); }
  void add(std::u8string_view glyph);
  int find(std::u8string_view glyph) const;
  std::u8string_view operator[](int index) const { return m_words[index]; }
};
```

with its definition

```c
Dictionary::Dictionary(std::u8string const& in)
{
  // Run over each glyph in the input.
  int glen;     // The number of bytes of the current glyph.
  for (char8_t const* glyph = in.data(); *glyph; glyph += glen)
  {
    glen = utf8_glyph_length(glyph);
    m_words.emplace_back(glyph, glen);
  }
}

void Dictionary::add(std::u8string_view glyph)
{
  if (find(glyph) == -1)
    m_words.push_back(glyph);
}

int Dictionary::find(std::u8string_view glyph) const
{
  for (int index = 0; index < m_words.size(); ++index)
    if (m_words[index] == glyph)
      return index;
  return -1;
}
```

I also used the following two helper functions

```c
char8_t to_hex_digit(int d)
{
  if (d < 10)
    return '0' + d;
  return 'A' + d - 10;
}

std::u8string to_hex_string(char8_t c)
{
  std::u8string hex_string;
  hex_string += to_hex_digit(c / 16);
  hex_string += to_hex_digit(c % 16);
  return hex_string;
}
```

Finally, here is the encoder function

```c
// Copy str to the returned filename, replacing every occurance of
// the utf8 glyphs in `from` with the corresponding one in `to`.
//
// All glyphs in `illegal` will be escaped with a percentage sign (%)
// followed by two hexidecimal characters for each code point of
// the glyph.
//
// If `from` does not contain the escape character, then each '%' will
// be replaced with "%%".
//
// All glyphs in `to` that are not in `from` are considered illegal
// and will also be escaped.
//
std::filesystem::path u8string_to_filename(std::u8string const& str,
    std::u8string const& illegal, std::u8string const& from, std::u8string const& to)
{
  using namespace detail::us2f;

  // All glyphs are found by their first byte.
  // Build a dictionary for each of the three strings.
  Dictionary from_dictionary(from);
  Dictionary to_dictionary(to);
  Dictionary illegal_dictionary(illegal);

  // The escape character is always illegal (is not allowed to appear on its own
  // in the output).
  illegal_dictionary.add({ &escape, 1 });

  // For each `from` entry there must exist one `to` entry.
  ASSERT(from_dictionary.size() == to_dictionary.size());

  std::filesystem::path filename;

  // Run over all glyphs in the input string.
  int glen;     // The number of bytes of the current glyph.
  for (char8_t const* gp = str.data(); *gp; gp += glen)
  {
    glen = utf8_glyph_length(gp);
    std::u8string_view glyph(gp, glen);
    // Perform translation.
    int from_index = from_dictionary.find(glyph);
    if (from_index != -1)
      glyph = to_dictionary[from_index];
    else if (*gp == escape)
    {
      filename += escape;
      filename += escape;
      continue;
    }
    // What is in illegal is *always* illegal - even when it is the result
    // of a translation.
    if (illegal_dictionary.find(glyph) != -1 ||
        // If an input glyph is not in the from_dictionary (aka, it
        // wasn't just translated) but it is in the to_dictionary -
        // then also escape it. This is necessary to make sure that
        // each unique input str results in a unique filename (and
        // consequently is reversible).
        (from_index == -1 && to_dictionary.find(glyph) != -1))
    {
      // Escape illegal glyphs.
      // Always escape the original input (not a possible translation),
      // otherwise we can't know if what the input was when decoding:
      // the input could have been translated first or not.
      for (int j = 0; j < glen; ++j)
      {
        filename += escape;
        filename += to_hex_string(gp[j]);
      }
      continue;
    }
    // Append the glyph to the filename.
    filename += glyph;
  }

  return filename;
}
```

And the decoder function

```c
std::u8string filename_to_u8string(std::filesystem::path const& filename,
    std::u8string const& from, std::u8string const& to)
{
  using namespace detail::us2f;

  std::u8string input = filename.u8string();
  std::u8string result;

  Dictionary from_dictionary(from);
  Dictionary to_dictionary(to);

  // First unescape all bytes in the filename.
  int glen;     // The number of bytes of the current glyph.
  for (char8_t const* gp = input.c_str(); *gp; gp += glen)
  {
    glen = utf8_glyph_length(gp);
    std::u8string_view glyph(gp, glen);
    // First translate escape sequences back - those are then always
    // original input.
    if (*gp == escape)
    {
      if (gp[1] == escape)
      {
        glen = 2;       // Skip the second escape character too.
        result += escape;
      }
      else
      {
        char8_t val = 0;
        for (int d = 1; d <= 2; ++d)
        {
          val <<= 4;
          val |= ('0' <= gp[d] && gp[d] <= '9') ? gp[d] - '0'
                                                : gp[d] - 'A' + 10;
        }
        result += val;
        glen = 3;       // Skip the two hex digits too.
      }
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      // Otherwise - if the character is in the from dictionary, it must have
      // been translated - otherwise it would have been escaped.
      int from_index = from_dictionary.find(glyph);
      if (from_index != -1)
        glyph = to_dictionary[from_index];
    }
    result += glyph;
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can find this all back (and the latest version) on [github](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/u8string_to_filename.cxx)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do with `filesystem::path`. The first step is to construct a `path` object from the sequence of characters. There are two-iterator constructors available, as well as constructors that take any of C++'s character types for encoding purposes.

Then, just [call `generic_u8string` on that `path` object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/generic_string); you will get a `std::u8string` (in C++20; in C++17, you get a `std::string`) containing the path formatted in a platform-neutral generic format. This string can later be used to reconstitute the `path` object as well.

Now, full round-tripping from the platform-specific format through `path` back to the platform-specific format is not really permitted. You can get the native string version of the path (`path::u8string` returns this), but there's no guarantee of a byte-for-byte identical string. There is a guarantee that the two strings will identify the same filesystem resource. So the differences, if they exist, are unimportant.

Comment: So constructing a path from the input string will still not lead to a path object such that path::filename() can itself be used to reconstitute the entire input string. Eg. https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y62R3zghdAp5rk9z will produce a file named "a" in directory "b". Note that the question was asking for a way to convert a sequence to a _filename_, not a _path_.

Comment: @Curious: If `path::filename` contained all of the information contained in the `path` object... what would be the point of it? Can you explain what you mean by "filename" in this context? That is, given your example in the previous comment of "/a/b", what part of that string is its "filename" in your mind? When you say "filename", `fs::path` defines it to mean one thing, but I think you mean it a different way. So just follow `fs::path`'s nomenclature and you'll be fine.

Comment: Filesystem APIs typically have the notion of directories and files like you point out. In this context, an `std::path` object has both. In the c++ stdlib nomenclature, the directories component is the parent path, and the filename is the file. What I'm asking for, is simply a way to convert a sequence of bytes to a filename such that the transformation can be reversed (so in the example "/a/b" to some `x` and then back to "/a/b") and not have the output get 1) conflated with directories by filesystem APIs or 2) be an invalid filename to begin with.

Comment: @Curious: This hasn't cleared up my question. You say "to a filename", but then you say "to some `x`". Which is it? Do you want it to be something that is considered a "filename" by some definition, or do you want it to just be anything, so long as it isn't "conflated with directories by filesystem APIs"? And what does that last bit mean anyway? Are you saying you want to encode a pathname in a way that you can decode it back into the pathname, but that filesystem APIs won't think of the encoded version as a pathname? Because BASE64 can do that.

Comment: _conflated with directories by filesystem APIs_ -- eg. if f("xyz") produces "/a/b/", then `f` is not valid for my usecase as "/a/b/" respresnts a directory. But Base32 sounds promising! (Base64 contains a forward slash, which would not work). Thanks!

Comment: @Curious: So... all you're looking for is a reversible binary-to-text function whose resulting text doesn't look like a pathname? You may want to restate your question to better represent what you're looking for. In particular get rid of the part about the filesystem APIs; that really threw things off-track.

Comment: Hmmm, I think the question would fail to capture the requirement that the output must not contain character sequences that are invalid as part of a filename for some platforms. (which apparently, base32 is advertised for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#Advantages)